# writing contents of list to one file in R

Tags: r

I have a list of a bunch of summaries of dataframes, and I would like to write them all to one file, so I can have a single text file containing the output of calling `summary()` on each data frame.

I tried this:

```
 dflist = lapply(1:4, function(x){df = data.frame(SID=paste("S",1:10,sep=""),matrix(runif(100),nrow=10,ncol=10))})
 sumlist  = lapply(dflist, function(df){summary(df)})
lapply(sumlist, function(i){write(i,"all_data_summary.txt",append=T )})
```

and it sort of works but it writes the levels of summaries of each variable to a new line, and does not include the variable name, like so:

```
S1     :1  
S10    :1  
S2     :1  
S3     :1  
S4     :1  
S5     :1  
(Other):4  
Min.   :0.1557  
1st Qu.:0.2284  
Median :0.5109  
Mean   :0.4707  
3rd Qu.:0.6471  
Max.   :0.9509  
NA
Min.   :0.05512  
1st Qu.:0.14310  
Median :0.20889  
Mean   :0.41891  
3rd Qu.:0.78261  
Max.   :0.97565  
NA
Min.   :0.01937  
1st Qu.:0.23876  
Median :0.57103  
Mean   :0.50806  
3rd Qu.:0.70491  
Max.   :0.95610  
NA
Min.   :0.0212  
1st Qu.:0.3445  
Median :0.5634  
Mean   :0.5554  
3rd Qu.:0.7484  
Max.   :0.9797
```

I would like the output to be of the form:

```
List Element 1              
SID X1  X2  X3  X4
S1     :1   Min.   :0.1557      Min.   :0.05512     Min.   :0.01937     Min.   :0.0212  
S10    :1   1st Qu.:0.2284      1st Qu.:0.14310     1st Qu.:0.23876     1st Qu.:0.3445  
S2     :1   Median :0.5109      Median :0.20889     Median :0.57103     Median :0.5634  
S3     :1   Mean   :0.4707      Mean   :0.41891     Mean   :0.50806     Mean   :0.5554  
S4     :1   3rd Qu.:0.6471      3rd Qu.:0.78261     3rd Qu.:0.70491     3rd Qu.:0.7484  
S5     :1   Max.   :0.9509      Max.   :0.97565     Max.   :0.95610     Max.   :0.9797  
(Other):4               
List Element 2              
SID X1  X2  X3  X4
S1     :1   Min.   :0.1557      Min.   :0.05512     Min.   :0.01937     Min.   :0.0212  
S10    :1   1st Qu.:0.2284      1st Qu.:0.14310     1st Qu.:0.23876     1st Qu.:0.3445  
S2     :1   Median :0.5109      Median :0.20889     Median :0.57103     Median :0.5634  
S3     :1   Mean   :0.4707      Mean   :0.41891     Mean   :0.50806     Mean   :0.5554  
S4     :1   3rd Qu.:0.6471      3rd Qu.:0.78261     3rd Qu.:0.70491     3rd Qu.:0.7484  
S5     :1   Max.   :0.9509      Max.   :0.97565     Max.   :0.95610     Max.   :0.9797
```

Any ideas?
Cheers,
Davy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proposed output looks like the standard printed output, so you might want to just take the approach of capturing the printed output to a file.  One simple way is to use the `sink` function, then have your `lapply` print the summaries.  Or you could use `capture.output` and save the results yourself (if you want to modify or check anything before saving).

If those are not suficcient then look at the code for the print function that is generating the output and see if you can modify that to put the information into a file.  It looks like the summary function on a data frame returns a table of character strings, so `print.table` would be the place to start.

Answer (score 4):

Skip the middle function and just do:

```
lapply(dflist, function(i){  capture.output( print(  summary(i) ) , 
                                    file="test.txt", append=TRUE)})
```

If you want the data to all be on the same line then set options(width=200) before running

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will most likely mangle the output based on the size of your window at the time but should work:

```
lapply(sumlist, function(i){out <- capture.output(print(i));cat(out,sep="\n",file="all_data_summary.txt",append=TRUE)}) -> .ans
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered transforming your output to yaml and storing it in a text file?

- It is human readable, which is principally what you want (I presume).
- You can recover your original data structure from the text file.

I think the package is called *yaml*.

Of course, if you need the output in the exact format you have indicated, I couldn't agree with the accepted answer more.