# Single column of data to multiple columned dataframe with no delimiter

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got some data output generated by windows software. 
It's a tab delimited rtf file, but upon export it is trasferred into one long column of data.
I'd like to use R to get it back into a dataframe to export as tab delimited so I can easily analyse the data:

Basically there are no delimiters but I know there should be, say, 7 columns in the finished file, so I'd like the dataframe to start a new row after 7 entries have gone in.

To illustrate, the output looks like this:

```
>Sample  
>Location  
>Test  
>Mean  
>Stdev  
>Status  
>Points  
>A  
>A1  
>XX1  
>0.034541  
>0.04596  
>UN  
>0  
>B  
>A1  
>XX2  
>0  
>0  
>TA  
>1
```

I'd like to parse it into this:

```
    >Sample   Location    Test      Mean     Stdev     Status   Points  
    >A        A1          XX1       0.03     0.04      UN       0  
    >B        A1          XX2       0        0         TA       1
```

I wasn't entirely sure how to search for this but the closest example of what I want to do is in this example:
[writing contents of list to one file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913857/writing-contents-of-list-to-one-file-in-r?rq=1)

But I couldn't work out how to apply the answers to my data, particularly the set width options (which I didnt fully follow, but could be about column number?), capture.output, and the two list elements which I don't think applies here.

Also open to BASH or awk solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a complete set of steps to take you through.

1. Read the file in as normal

   ```
   d = read.table("/tmp/tmp.txt", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
   ```

   This gives a data frame with one column.
2. Next we alter the number of rows and columns:

   ```
   d = unlist(d)
   dim(d) = c(7, nrow(d)/7)
   d = t(d)
   ##Or 
   d = matrix(as.matrix(d), ncol=7, byrow=TRUE)
   ```
3. Then we remove the ">" symbol:

   ```
   d = gsub(">", "", d)
   ```

   here we replace ">" with nothing ""
4. Then sort out the column headings:

   ```
   colnames(d) = d[1,]
   d = d[-1,]
   ```

Comment: Wow, it really is very simple when you spell it out like that isn't it. Thank you csgillespie

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
# Read data
x<-read.table(textConnection('>Sample  
>Location  
>Test  
>Mean  
>Stdev  
>Status  
>Points  
>A  
>A1  
>XX1  
>0.034541  
>0.04596  
>UN  
>0  
>B  
>A1  
>XX2  
>0  
>0  
>TA  
>1'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# Convert to matrix
mat<-matrix(as.matrix(x),ncol=7,byrow=TRUE)
# Dump as tab delimited
write.table(mat,'file.tab',sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other solution, I keep it because there is a further treatment :

```
matrix(gsub('>','',dat$V1),ncol=7,byrow=T)
colnames(dat) <- dat[1,]
> dat <- dat[-1,]
> dat
    Sample Location Test  Mean       Stdev     Status Points
[1,] "A"    "A1"     "XX1" "0.034541" "0.04596" "UN"   "0"   
[2,] "B"    "A1"     "XX2" "0"        "0"       "TA"   "1"
```

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea it was simple. I thought I would have to use an 'apply' and missed these neat solutions.